# Probability in a deck of Spanish cards

Tags: probability, permutations, card-games

I have a deck of Spanish cards. (It would work the same with poker decks).

If I ask a person to give me a number $X$ and to another to give me a card type $T$
In a given permutation of the decks, I have shuffled them previously.

What is the probability to have guessed the right position and card type?

*Example:* Position $X=12$ and card type "$5$ of hearts" and I have shuffled the identity just once.

*My thinking:* I change card types identifying then uniquely by number, cause they won't repeat. But I don't know if I should really have into account the permutation or just try to calculate the probability, in that case the prob would be $\frac{1}{52}$. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $52$ equally likely positions in which a given card could be.  Therefore, the probability that a given card $T$ is in position $X$ is simply $1/52$.